# Android camera to opencv cv::mat

Tags: android, opencv, c++11

I built .so for c++ used in android.I want to get camera preview image and send it to my so interface to implement my algorithm.
Question comes when I get the image whose format is yuv and its send a struct including width height,*data to my interface.
How can I convert image format to opencv cv::Mat in my .so to overcome this problem.
Any reply will be appreciated.

Comment: For conversion, you may use standard [`libyuv`](https://github.com/lemenkov/libyuv), and then `cv::Mat()` constructor, which takes width, height, type and data pointer as params

Comment: I already did cv::Mat Image(img_copy.height * 3/2,img_copy.width,CV_8UC1,img_copy.data)
cv::cvtColor(Image, Image,CV_YUV2BGR_NV21);

Comment: Where is the problem then ?

Comment: wouldn't you need `CV_8UC3` since the yuv buffer is 3 channel buffer